# Render separate date and time fields using form's DateTimeField()

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

This is what am trying to achieve

[image]

```
Forms.py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

     Recorded_datetime = forms.DateTimeField()
```

I want the field to have a seperate date and time input like in the case of `pub_date` field in the famous poll app.
What should I call in the template to achieve that? I have tried `SplitDateTimeWidget` but still cant achieve that.
What Am getting is
 [image]

Help please. Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work about the `SplitDateTimeWidget`?

Comment: @jproffitt I dont know Its usage, I did `Recorded_datetime = forms.SplitDateTimeWidget()` and I did't exactly know how to call it in template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `SplitDateTimeWidget`. This is how you change the widget:

```
Recorded_datetime = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.SplitDateTimeWidget())
```

Comment: Its splitting them pretty well but how do I add the date and time pickers?

Comment: I got it working, What I did was to subclass class `AdminSplitDateTime` then override `format_output` method and put bootstrap date and time pickers there.

Comment: @alexxio whats code example?